# Inside DataSnap Server Method, How to read all request header

Tags: delphi, datasnap

When I know the name of a custom header, is possible to get the value this way:

```
function TControllerAplicacao.EchoString(Value: string): string;
var
 objWebModule: TWebModule; //need Web.HTTPApp
begin
  objWebModule := GetDataSnapWebModule; //need Datasnap.DSHTTPWebBroker

 Result := objWebModule.Request.GetFieldByName('MY-KEY-NAME');

end;
```

But on my ServerMethod I need to get all key-pairs from Request-Header. How to do ?

There is the rawHeaders (using IdHTTP, IdHTTPWebBrokerBridge, IdHTTPHeaderInfo) but I can't to access it inside ServerMethod from DATASNAP REST. Any idea about ?

Comment: The question is: why do you want to do this?

Comment: I want to monitor and identify legacy clients using services.

Comment: In other hand I already have other technology doing this analysing many informations to identify errors and failures and server behaviors.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it with DMVC Framework from Danielle Teti. So I migrate the EndPoint Style DataSnap to DMVC.